# sudo: apt: command not found after performing sudo apt remove gnupg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, raspberry-pi

Before writing the original issue I am facing, I think it'd be best to provide some background.

**Background** I was trying to register a new source to get packages when running apt-get to finally install azure-iot-sdk-c-dev to use the code to communicate to IoT Hub.

I ran in to issue when tried running the following command.

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From the error it seemed that my PI doesn't have dirmngr directory. So I started looking for solutions. One of the solution was to use the following commands

> sudo apt remove gnupg
>
> sudo apt install --reinstall gnupg2
>
> sudo apt install dirmngr

Even though I was informed about the potential damage of the first command I assumed performing the second command would fix things up, but the second command is not running.

**Issue** It is giving me errors like *sudo: apt: command not found* to fix that I tried the following

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnupg2
>
> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

But both errors out stating -bash: apt-get: command not found

**EDIT 1**
After trying **sudo aptitude install apt**, I get the following,
[image]
I tried the following afterward
[image]

Then manually created preferences
[image]

now stuck at update
[image]

Comment: What does **`find / -name apt-get`** shows ? Does it lists `/usr/bin/apt-get`. If yes, then try using **`sudo /usr/bin/apt-get`** with install , update or upgrade.

Comment: Ok will try once I reach home

Comment: Hi, I didn't find /usr/bin/apt-get listed, what next try seeing whether I have gdebi or one of the programs mentioned by @AFH.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on in your system. You should try suggestions by @AFH depending on what you have installed. Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing `gnupg` should not have affected whether `apt` and `apt-get` are installed, though removing some libraries may stop them working correctly.

Possible solutions depend on what you have installed:-

- if you have `gdebi`, then you can install `apt*` from the `.deb` files down-loaded from LaunchPad;
- if you have `aptitude` or `synaptic`, you can use one of these to restore `apt*`;
- otherwise, mount the install disc for the system, then modify `PATH` to reference the utilities on the install disc;
- if all else fails, boot the install disc and reinstall the OS over the top.

If you use an install disc, make sure you down-load the latest for the release you are running.

There may be other solutions (such as using `chroot` to address your installed system from a booted install disc), but without understanding how `apt*` were lost, I am reluctant to suggest more.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so something did get deleted? and My options are to repair or reinstall?

Comment: Did you follow @C0deDaedalus' suggestion (you will find `locate` a lot faster than `find`)? With what result? Obviously some sort of repair is needed: you will need to find which method involves the least work. Since I don't know what has gone wrong with your system, I don't know how much work each of my options will entail, though I expect the last will not be the easiest.

Comment: I will follow his suggestion once I reach back home in evening, then will post my updates. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: When I run the command as suggested by @C0deDaedalus, I see a lot of find commands with permission denied message and I do not see /usr/bin/apt-get either.
I do not know whether I have gdebi, synaptic or aptitude but I will make sure to learn to find to see whether these programs are installed or not. In case I do not find the programs installed can I from the internet try installing those first?
Please pardon me if I've missed something obvious, I'm completely new to this and Linux.

Comment: I seem to have aptitude, I used dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii' | grep aptitude. Now I need to learn to use aptitude to restore apt*. Will keep you posted sir.

Comment: I maybe getting lost when trying to restore apt*, could you please suggest specific of the command.

Comment: Although it has an interactive mode, `aptitude` can take its commands from its run string, just like `apt` and `apt-get`, so `aptitude install apt` should restore your `apt` command.

Comment: Thank you for responding sir, I tried running *sudo aptitude install apt* and got a list of errors/messages, I will edit my post to share the details please have a look.

Comment: I've not seen messages like those before: I suspect you're now probably going to have to reinstall over the top, as it's going to take more time trying to avoid this than doing it. You shouldn't lose anything, but it's always wise to back up first.

Comment: I am fine reinstalling but my worry is, I may end up here when trying to create a connection string and having to find that there is no dirmngr :( Please see my original post's first paragraph.

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla Why don't you just 'sudo apt install dirmngr' ? Why purge gnupg at all, when you have gnupg installed, but not dirmngr? That's what I did last time I started from a clean Debian install.

Comment: @Anders Good Idea, I for some reason thought that is required to run all three commands(sudo apt remove gnupg, sudo apt install --reinstall gnupg2 and sudo apt install dirmngr).
Quick question, I see messages with W: or E: after executing a command in terminal, what these signify, a link will help.

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla You should include some more info, does it come when you use cd, apt, gnupg ? All of them? I am guessing its apt where they mean Warning: and Error:

Comment: Thanks, you answered what I was looking for, and sorry for not providing an example.